# Как сверстать два блока?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сверстать два блока: один слева, второй справа, ширина 1-го зависит от внутреннего контента, а 2-ой от ширины 1-го блока?

Comment: В каком смысле ширина второго от первого?

Comment: а где Ваш код ?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, чтобы добиться такого результата с помощью `css`, есть только один способ: использование флексбоксов. Необходимо задать родителю `display: flex;`, а тому из блоков, ширина которого определяется шириной другого блока прописать свойство `flex: auto;`.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.flex-container .item-title {
  background: #a7a7a7;
}
.flex-container .item-descr {
  flex: auto;
  background: #cecece;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item-title">Наименование товара:</div>
  <div class="item-descr">Some product</div>
</div>
```